# Looting Dark elixir?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want DE. If I am attacking a village which has 1000 DE available for loot, do I get it all if I destroy his de storage or do I also need to destroy his de drill and Town hall. What if I use lightning spell on his storage only and demolish it completely... How much I will get?

Comment: How cn i delete it.. It repeated by mistake

Comment: you can delete your own question, just go to the options button I think

Comment: Resource storage structures are immune to damaging spells. So, if you use lightning spells on his storage only, you'll get nothing as you deal no damage to them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you need to destroy dark elixir drill and dark elixir storage to get all elixir.You don't need to destroy Town Hall to get dark elixir.

Here is some pictures to show you full and emtry drills:

[image: Emtry Drill]1]
Emtry Drill

[image: Full Drill]
Full Drill